# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is unsubscriptable when using JIRA API

Tags: python, json

My code is this:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
import re
import datetime
baseUrl = 'https://jira01.zz.com:8443/'
api='rest/api/2/search?jql='
jiraUser = 'qqqqq'
jiraPassword = 'qqqq123'

date_today = datetime.date.today()
date_tomorrow = date_today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print date_today
print date_tomorrow
message = "Alert for qq.com"

jql = 'project IN (SYS) AND status IN (Open, "In Progress", Reopened) AND labels IN (sys-status) AND createdDate >= "%s" and createdDate < "%s" AND Summary ~ "%s"' % (date_today, date_tomorrow, message)
maxResults = '1'
output = requests.get(baseUrl+api+jql+maxResults,auth=(jiraUser,jiraPassword),verify=False)
if output.json['issues']:
        print baseUrl+'browse/'+output.json['issues'][0]['key']
else:
        print "No ticket"
```

I get the following error:
2014-03-19
2014-03-20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test10_jql.py", line 22, in 
    if output.json['issues']:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is unsubscriptable

Answer (score 0):

`output.json` is a method, not a data attribute. You need to call it.